# How to submit twitter bootstrap javascript buttons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm talking about the Twitter Boostrap radio buttons from here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

I have used them in my view file like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
     <input type="button" name="type" class="btn" value="Car">
     <input type="button" name="type" class="btn" value="Bicycle">
</div>
```

But when I submit the form and trying to validate those, I can't get their values...

`echo $_POST['type'];` is empty... so how should I access & validate the above "radio" buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin only work for appearances : it does not set anything (except the class). You have to use your own JS to set some real radio buttons, or a unique hidden input.

```js
$('[data-toggle="buttons-radio"] > .btn').on('click',function() {
    $('#someHiddenInput').val($(this).val());
});
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/c3jsU/)

It seems that `type="button"` are not submitted anyway (on my Firefox).

---

This is one approach, an other would be to check on submit which one has the `.active` class.

Comment: Thanks for this... I have made some modifications to your code, so when clicking on these buttons, the javascript function is setting an value in the hidden input `:)`. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution  derived from Sherbrow's answer. It lets you have several Bootstrap-style radio buttons and keep them in sync with a hidden input with just one line of code. All you need to do is always place a hidden input inside of the .btn-group.

HTML:

```
        <!-- Vehicle
        ================================================== -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="selectRecipients">Vehicle</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" value="car">Car</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" value="bicyle">Bicycle</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="vehicle" value=""></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Food
        ================================================== -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="selectRecipients">Vehicle</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" value="apples">Apples</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" value="oranges">Oranges</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="food" value=""></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
    /** Associate UI-only radio buttons with hidden fields **/
    $('[data-toggle="buttons-radio"] > button').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val( $(this).val() );
        alert( $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val() );
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KyHMp/1/

In a live setting, you'd want to set one of the button as the default active button (.active) and give a default value to the hidden field.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't actually even related to Twitter Bootstrap.  You should consider having unique names for the "name" attributes.

Comment: Ummm, no. There's a reason the buttons are named the same.